# find symlink to a known file /etc/init.d/ portmap

Tags: find

I'm looking for the /etc/rc.X/ softlink to /etc/init.d/portmap.

Does anyone know where portmap is called?

How can I find all symlinks to a file?

Chris

Answer (score 2):

You can use find with the -l option for this.

```
sudo find / -mount -lname {/dir/to/file}
```

- -mount: prevents searching on other filesystems
- -l: Follow symbolic links.

Some examples I found:

[How to find all symbolic links to a given file/directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/98488/how-to-find-all-symbolic-links-to-a-given-file-directory)

[How to find symlink](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-symlink/)